# How to block user with immediate effect in auth0

Tags: auth0

I tried auth0 and I face a problem where I can't block or force logout a user.

After i blocked a user from auth0 console, The user who was logged in could still access the routes.

I used express-openid-connect middleware and requiresAuth()

I suppose this is a common problem with JWT based service ?  and should I implement a statefull session to manage user for these kind of use cases ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JWT based services it’s common practice to make the access token lifetime a short one, e.g. 10-15 minutes. That way user can still access the api inside a short window but soon the token needs to be refreshed. And when token refresh takes place the authentication service gets called and can reject granting a new token.

So you can make sure your access token lifetime is short enough and that should be enough to satisfy the security requirements.

It’s of course technically possible that you implement stateful session to check user info on each request but you should not call Auth0 api in this case cause you are going to hit their rate limiter and it slows down your api requests. Some sort of sync to your server side fast read database/cache would be needed.